# I don't understand the proof of theorem 7.25 in Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

if $K$ is compact,  $f_{n}$ is a complex continuous function on defined on $K$ for $n = 1,2,3,...$

and if $f_n$ is pointwise bounded and equicontinuous on $K$, then.

$f_n$ is uniformly bounded on $K$.

I don't understand, in the proof, why since $K$ is compact, there are finitely many points $p_1, ..., p_r$ in $K$ such that to every $x \in K$ corresponds at least one $p_i$ with $d(x,p_i) < \delta$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the open cover of $K$ given by $\{N_\delta(k)\}_{k\in K}$.  Apply compactness to find a finite subcover.