# Can bounded set be covered by finite open balls with same radius? (In metric space)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

[I don't understand the proof of theorem 7.25 in Rudin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194921/i-dont-understand-the-proof-of-theorem-7-25-in-rudin)

After reading this, I know that compact set can be covered by finite open balls (Where centres are in the set) with same radius, we also know that compact set is the bounded set, so, loosely, do we have this property in bounded set?

Comment: For any bounded set $S$, there is some $R$ such that a single ball of radius $R$ and center in $S$ covers it. A subset $S$ of a metric space such that *for all* $r>0$ there is a finite family of open balls of radius $r$ with centers in $S$ which cover $S$ is said to be *totally bounded*, and it's a more restrictive condition than boundedness. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you, I just searched for some examples that some set bounded but not totally bounded.

Comment: You already have a good  answer from Paul Frost, but here's an even simpler one. Let $X$ be any infinite set and define a metric $d$ on it by letting $d(x,y)=1$ whenever$x\neq y$ (and of course $d(x,x)=0$). The space $X$ is bounded, but any ball of radius $<1$ contains only one point (its center), so you need infinitely many such balls to cover $X$.

Comment: Also have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma#Characterization_of_finite_dimension In infinite-dimensional normed spaces, closed balls are bounded but never compact.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Graceful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to cover a given bounded subset $B$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ by finitely many open balls $B(x_i,r)$, where $r > 0$ is arbitrary. In general it is impossible.

Let $X = \mathbb R$ and $d(x,y) =  \min(\lvert x - y \rvert, 1)$. This $d$ is a metric which is equivelent to the standard Euclidean metric $\lvert x - y \rvert$. Clearly $X$ is a bounded subset of $(X,d)$, but for no $r < 1$ we can cover $X$ by finitely many $B(x_i,r)$. This is true because in that case $B(x_i,r) = (x_i - r, x_i+r) \subset B(0,\lvert x_i \rvert + r)$.